# Can anyone explain the core concept of model in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angular-directive

HTML Code:

```
<mydirective></mydirective>
<input type="button" ng-click="showText()" value="Show Service Text" />
```

Js Code:

```
    var app = angular.module('demo', []);
    app.service('myService', function () {
        var text = { id: 1, value: 'hello' };

        this.getText = function () {
            return text;
        }
    });
    app.controller('demoController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
        $scope.showText = function () {
            alert(myService.getText().value);
        }
    }]);
```

Now, I will show the 2 versions of my directive:
1) First Version:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function () {
            var controller = ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
                $scope.randomtext = myService.getText();
            }];

            var template = '<div><input type="text" ng-model="randomtext.value" /><span ng-bind="randomtext.value"></span></div>'

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {},
                controller: controller,
                template: template
            };
        });
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/z4q0zugh/2/)

When I use like this then the service variable is updated on updating the input field.

2) Second Version:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function () {
            var controller = ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
                $scope.randomtext = myService.getText().value;
            }];

            var template = '<div><input type="text" ng-model="randomtext" /><span ng-bind="randomtext"></span></div>'

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {},
                controller: controller,
                template: template
            };
        });
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ru6zhm48/1/)

When I use like this then the service variable is not updated on updating the input field.
Can anyone explain why the behaviour is like this?

Comment: has any of the answers answer your question. Please accept it to become a reference for future reader.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript problem not an AngularJS problem. You're having problems with differentiating between a reference type value and a primitive type value.

The example below should clear the misunderstanding:

```js
var myObject = {
  value: 1
};

var $scope = {};

$scope.data = myObject;

$scope.data.value = 3;

// This should alert the value of 3
window.alert(myObject.value);
```

The snippet above should alert the value of `3`, since you're changing the `reference` value of `myObject` that was passed to `$scope.data`.

Check the example below and it should show you that primitive values doesn't work that way.

```js
var myObject = { value: 1 };
var $scope = {};

$scope.data = myObject.value;

$scope.data = 3;

// This should alert the value of 1
window.alert(myObject.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First version (The working one)**

```
$scope.randomtext = myService.getText();
```

This makes $scope.randomtext a reference to the same text object in your service, so whenever $scope.randomtext is changed with your input field, the text object in the service will also change and you get the updated value when you alert it.

**Second version (The one that is not working)**

```
$scope.randomtext = myService.getText().value;
```

in this version $scope.randomtext is NOT a reference to the text object, the assignment operator creates a new copy of the value property into $scope.randomtext, making it a totally new variable that is not tied in any way with the service, so whenever you change randomtext in your input field, the object in myservice will not feel a thing.